# ACL setting on XPage not working as expected

Tags: xpages

I am trying to restrict access to an xpage. In the acl of the application I have Manager access. When I try to decrease the access level for myself via the acl property of the xpage to "NOACCESS" I still gain access to the xpage as I would normally do. I would have expected to gain no access at all:

```
<xp:this.acl>
        <xp:acl>
        <xp:this.entries>
                <xp:aclEntry type="ANONYMOUS" right="NOACCESS"></xp:aclEntry>
                <xp:aclEntry type="DEFAULT" right="READER"></xp:aclEntry>
                <xp:aclEntry name="Malin Andersson/O=banken"
                    right="NOACCESS" type="USER">
                </xp:aclEntry>
            </xp:this.entries>
        </xp:acl>
    </xp:this.acl>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you try `name="CN=Malin Andersson/O=banken"` ? I see, that you copied the example from help, but it still looks wrong like that...

Comment: I have tried several options. This one was actually from an IBM wiki (adapted the Organizational name).

Comment: I tried <xp:aclEntry
     fullName="${javascript:session.getEffectiveUserName();}"
     right="NOACCESS" type="USER">
    </xp:aclEntry>  but then I get the error message: Unexpected error computing XSP page access control list authorization. Refer to log files for more information.

Comment: use name="${javascript:session.getEffectiveUserName();}" instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the entry with your name **first**.

Only the **first** entry that matches the user by name, group or role is used.

DEFAULT applies to everyone and "wins" in your case.

(see [Mastering XPages: A Step-by-Step Guide to XPages Application Development and the XSP Language (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0133373371) page 1043)

Comment: ... and if your user entry is the first entry make sure your name is specified in canonical form like Torsten showed in his comment.

Comment: I went to upvote this and the system told that ... I already upvoted in 2016. That's means I completely forgot that the answer existed until I ran into the problem again. LOL.